# How to use screen.width value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, screen

As you all know there is a difference between window windth and screen width values, but screen width is not working for me in react, I don't know why but that what it is.

So when I try this code in my react application :

```
console.log(window.innerWidth);
```

I get a value, but that is not what I am looking for, I am looking for the screen width, so when I try this code :

```
console.log(screen.width);
```

I get an error in my terminal telling me that :

Line 121:  Unexpected use of 'screen'  no-restricted-globals

So what should I do to solve this ? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `window.screen.width`

Comment: With that you can also check: window.screen.availWidth Useful stuff!

Comment: @tarzenchugh and Bebolicious : both of them are good, I took tarzn solution, thank you :D